# How to mount the sub path of PVC to the specific path in container

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a storage provided by cloud provider. It's able to mount the storage to container via PVC.

Is there any way to specify the subpath of the disk then mounting to specific path of container.

I tried the custom values as below, but it does not work.

```
Persistence:
  Enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires Persistence.Enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  ExistingClaim: ci-jenkins-data

  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  # StorageClass: "-"

  Annotations: {}
  AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  Size: 100Gi
  volumes:
    - name: ci-jenkins-data
      mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      subPath: /volume/jenkins
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since one PVC can be claimed only once, Iam assuming you want to mount sub folders in volume in single pod. I have specified subpath in volumeMounts section as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-lamp-site
spec:
    containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: "rootpasswd" 
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        name: site-data
        subPath: mysql
    - name: php
      image: php:7.0-apache
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: site-data
        subPath: html
    volumes:
    - name: site-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-lamp-site-data
```

Above snippet is copied from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

Iam sure you might have tried hostpath however 1.9 raw block volume support may help your case.

Let me know if this helps or not.

Regards
Sudhakar

Comment: Does not work for me. I got an error like: failed to create subPath directory for volumeMount "site-data" of container "php"